# DeprecationWarning: Using a string as loader options is deprecated

Tags: node.js, string, webpack, deprecated, bigcommerce

So I'm updating a website using BigCommerce's Stencil CLI and now I'm suddenly getting this warning or error.

`(node:4956) [DEP_WEBPACK_RULE_LOADER_OPTIONS_STRING] DeprecationWarning: Using a string as loader options is deprecated (ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[0].options)`

I did just get done reinstalling my Nodejs node modules and I'm guessing it has something to do with webpack v5 from the few results on google that pop up when I search the error, but I can't find any results that give me any clues on how to get rid of this error. I'm just a beginner at all of this, so as detailed of an explanation as possible on how to fix the issue would be appreciated.  My node version is 12.0.0.

Answer (score -1):

I checked on some of the GitHub issues for the cli and found a similar issue that has a few developers sharing solutions. It's not 1:1 but is a similar error around a DeprecationWarning. Also, did the CLI complete its installation?

This appears to be a warning rather than an error. If the cli completed the install, you should be good to move on with your theme customizations. However, if you wanted to dig into this warning, I'd recommend checking out that thread I mentioned, to see if any of those work for you! Find it here: https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/issues/742